# Import has been successfully finished but tables empty

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-s3

I need to backup a database all work fine but for import it's not working

I use this bash script for backup

```
databases=`mysql -u MyData -p$mysqlpass -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v "\(Database\|information_schema\|performance_schema\|mysql\|test\)"`
for db in $databases; do
   mysqldump -u MyData -p$mysqlpass --force --opt --databases "$db" | gzip -c > "$tmpfile"
   s3cmd put "$tmpfile" "$object"
done;
```

My file.sql contains all data and structure. After i import the file i receive this message:

> Import has been successfully finished, 148 queries executed. (1458392798-19-03-16-14-06-38-MyData.sql)

But the database is empty... 
Why i cant import ?

if i use phpmyadmin for export/import it's work fine, it's not work only with mysqldump

Thanks you

Comment: I have test with command line too but not work `mysql -u root -p tester < file.sql`

Comment: You need to provide more details. How did you check for the imported data?

Comment: The backup script you have shown would, *at best*, back up only one database -- the last one -- because it's overwriting each one with the next.  Also `--force` should *never* be used unless you have a specific reason to do so.  It is designed to ignore errors (!!?) and is only valid when you know there is an error, you know you will lose data, but you want to capture as much as possible, skipping over the error and its accompanying data loss.  In light of this, you need to explain how you know the backup is "working."